# How to pass the user invoking command as default parameter in discord.py bot.command?

Tags: discord.py, command, python-3.10

I am trying to make a rank based system for my `discord.py` bot.

I want to implement a rank command which returns the rank of the specified user. By default I want the specified user to be the one invoking the command, i.e. `ctx.message.author`.

```
async def rank(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=ctx.message.author):
```

I know this is invalid syntax, but how could I achieve such a thing?

My discord.py version is `1.7.3`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make `user` default to None (using typing.Optional) and replace it with ctx.message.author inside the command.

e.g

```py
async def rank(self, ctx, user: typing.Optional[discord.Member]=None):
    if not user:
        user = ctx.message.author
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Lambda Expressions in Python:

```
async def rank(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=lambda ctx:ctx.message.author):
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)